# Angular repeat filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a message object which I want to display in a table,
I don't want to display all properties of the message so I set some of them false and I want to filter the properties that are set true and display them

Message Object:

```
message0 = {
    id: {
        wert: 0,
        status: pr_active.id
    },
    category: {
        wert: 'General',
        status: pr_active.category
    },
    icon_id: {
        wert: '1',
        status: pr_active.id.icon_id
    },
    text: {
        wert: 'Success',
        status: pr_active.id.text
    }
};

    scope.messages = [message0, message1, message2];
```

ngRepeat:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter: {category : category}">
            <td ng-repeat="property in message | filter: {status:true}">
                {{property.wert}}
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I'm using a status-Object which contains the status for every possible property, so that I can connect it to the header of the table

```
        pr_active = {
        id: 'false',
        category: 'false',
        icon_id: 'true',
        text: 'true',
    }
```

The problem is, that every property is displayed, even the one's that should be false.

Also the properties are displayed in the wrong order (they are ordered alphabetically), how can I use the default order that I defined

Comment: can u provide a plnkr?

Answer (score 0):

You don't define an order on an object in JavaScript (see [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)).
Thus you'd have to define an order for you properties manually.
But this might already solve your problem:

Suppose you must define the order of the properties you want to display, then you might as well just define those properties you want to see:

```
$scope.properties = [
  // 'id', // just use a comment if you don't want to see them
  // 'category',
  'icon_id',
  'text'
]
```

Then you simply have to iterate over the `properties` array in your inner `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter: {category : category}">
  <td ng-repeat="property in properties">
    {{message[property].wert}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have to use the properties I don't want to display for other things (e.g. the category for checking if the message belongs to the current category-tab), so commenting them out is not an option. The reason why I've chosen an object for every property is that I want to save the display-status so I can't just define the properties in an array but thanks for the array-idea I'll try to work with it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?:

```
pr_active = {
        id: false,
        category: false,
        icon_id: true,
        text: true
    }
```